# Event with function components

Tags: reactjs

I have just started learning REACT and has taken some courses online. I have created a very simple function component, and I want to implement an event, that the parent components can consume. I can find a lot of samples and articles on the net on how to do this using bind (int the constructor) with class components. However I have not found any articles on function components. Anyone has a simple sample or article on how to do this? In general I see many recommendations on using function components over class components, but much more articles and frameworks where people are using class components. Are function components fairly new?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
  Button
} from "reactstrap";

const DropdownPaging = props => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(10);
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  function dropDownChanged(val) {
    setSelectedValue(val);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &lt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button outline color="dark">
              &gt;
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
              <DropdownToggle caret outline color="dark">
                {selectedValue}
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(10)}>
                  10
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(25)}>
                  25
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(50)}>
                  50
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem onClick={() => dropDownChanged(100)}>
                  100
                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </Dropdown>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownPaging;
```

Comment: FunctionComponents are not new but React hooks are 'fairly' new. Like the useState function you are using is a 'hook'. I recommend checking [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-QO-KO90iQ) of reactconf where they introduce hooks and their diffrences.

Comment: @Stutje really good video around the function components part. Thanks for the link appreciated. However it does not show my main question. How do I implement a custom event to my component so I can do something like <DropdownPaging someEvent="myEventFunction">

Comment: all those events or data is passed inside the `props` in your function declaration. You can destruct `props` like `const DropdownPaging = 
 ({someEvent}) => {...}` and then you can pass data like `<DropdownPaging someEvent={myEventFunction} />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, functional components are there from a long back, One of the feature that functional components got new  is handling the state and life cycle method

So before the version of 16.8, functional components were purely used to render the presentational part, so it can't handle state or handle life cycle methods

So when dealing with big applications the problem was if you need to have a single state variable you need to change the functional components to class components

So then after the release of 16.8 react team introduced hooks, so now you can handle state and life cycle methods with the help of hooks

How it came to hooks is basically

1. Render Props - Sharing Code between components - [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)
2. Hoc Components - Reusing component logic - [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

You can read more on [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) about hooks.

Example of using hooks

1. Async data loading - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59607803-so-async-data-loading-useeffect-53jhd)
2. Using state - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59565615-so-updating-state-using-usestate-546ye)
3. Rendering table data and disabling the row based on state key - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59574618-so-antd-disable-row-r7btk)
4. Custom Hook - window resize - [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usewindowsize-customhook-2b1k8)

If you are updating and trying above codesandbox fork it and update. (It will be helpful for others :) )

Comment: OK, so hooks are the key word. That is why i properly did not find anything on events with functions. Many of the samples you paste is about handling events within the component. But I am looking for implementing your own events in your component, that parents can use.

Comment: are you looking for custom Hooks

Comment: I have added the custom hook example for window resize, so you can resize the window it will show the width/height calc, I hope this have cleared your clarifications

Comment: Yes I think so. I have a component. When using that component I want consumers to be able to sign-up for events from my component. In my sample when users changes the dropdown.

Comment: Cool, happy to help , If it helped you kindly vote and accept so it will be helpful for others, don't consider hooks as complex basically a function which handles its seperately like utils or helper function so you can have the state and life cycle methods seperately

Comment: I went through all the samples and still looking for a sample where I can do something like this <DropdownPaging someEvent="myEventFunction"> with my function components. Maybe it is not hooks I am looking for?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, kindly post as a different question, since the question was asking on functional components

Comment: It is the thing I am trying to ask in the question. But I am so new the question could be better. In my function component I want to add an event. So everytime somebody change the value in my dropdown I want to pass that event to the component using my component. So the they can do something like <DropdownPaging someEvent=.... a

Comment: like an hoc component ?

Comment: When I read this article it looks more like that is about passing general information between components. So I am not sure if that is the way REACT implements events? In angular, C#. It must be very common in REACT to to create a custom component, that also provides events like onClick, valueAdded, myCustomEvent ... In the article from the link you provided I dont see anything like <MyComponent onClick='functionInthisComponent'.

Comment: I have a video on pluralsight where they do it from a class component. They do something like this.props.onEvenClick(clicksNew). Following you can do something like this where the component are used. <EvenCounter onEvenClick=...

Comment: They call the chapter Event Components that is why I called it events. In all other programming language i worked with, it would be called an event, but could be differently in REACT.

Comment: I really didnt understood what you are trying to achieve, kindly add a new question, question was more on functional components i think i have added info on that

Comment: Add a new post. Hope it is more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612791/implementing-events-in-a-react-function-component