# Implementing events in a REACT function component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to implement my own custom events. I asked the question here but the word event seems to confuse my question. I was asked to add a new question, so I will try to do my best in another way:

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609279/event-with-function-components/59609394?noredirect=1#comment105387900_59609394)

My component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const DropdownPaging2 = props => {
  function myClickFunc(val) {
    alert("WHAT SHOULD I ADD HERE TO FIRE MY EVENT TO THE CONSUMING COMPONENT");
  }

  return <div onClick={() => myClickFunc(100)}>CLICK me</div>;
};

export default DropdownPaging2;
```

Using my component in another components (comsuming component) render function:

```
<DropdownPaging2></DropdownPaging2>
```

I would like implement so I can pass a new event to the consuming component. Something lige this:

```
<DropdownPaging2 myCustomEvent={() => myCustomEvent(100)}></DropdownPaging2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass functions as props to your DropdownPaging2 component like you mentioned:

```
<DropdownPaging2 myEvent={() => myCustomEvent(100)}></DropdownPaging2>
```

And then use it in the component like this.

```
const DropdownPaging2 = props => {
  const myClickFunc = (val) => {
    if(props.myEvent){
      props.myEvent();
    } else {
      // default if no function is passed
     }

  }

  return <div onClick={() => myClickFunc(100)}>CLICK me</div>;
};

export default DropdownPaging2;
```

This way you are free to pass a custom function

Comment: Ok that was really easy. Thanks just tested it here. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bird-woed4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Just make your component use the *custom* callback if it was passed as a prob, otherwise use the *default* one.

```
return <div onClick={prop.myCustomEvent ? prop.myCustomEvent : () => myClickFunc(100)}>CLICK me</div>;
```